# Using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT with EXTRA_INITIAL_URI and a file:// Uri

Tags: android, document-provider

Is it possible to use `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`  with  a file:// format Uri as an `DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` extra, to have DocumentsProvider start navigation in the file's location?

In my app I give user an option to use a custom settings file and when he chooses this option, am example default file is created at app's data folder (returned by `getExternalFilesDir`).

When selecting a custom file, I want the DocumentsProvider to open the folder where currently selected file is located with use of `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`. There's no problem if some file was previously chosen with an `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` Intent, as returned Uri is of `content://` format.

Problem exists before user selects the file for the first time and only Uri to created default custom file is available. File is created by use of `File.createNewFile` in directory returned by `Context.getExternalFilesDir`, and Uri is generated with use of `Uri.fromFile(file)`, resulting in a `file://` format Uri.

Here's a simple example code:

Creating custom file. Returns Uri like `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.testsapp/files/customFile.txt`

```
fun createFile(context: Context): Uri {
        val appDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
        val customFile = File(appDir, "customFile.txt")
        customFile.createNewFile()
        // writing to customFile via FileOutputStream(file)
        return Uri.fromFile(customFile)
    }
```

Letting user pick a custom file:

```
fun pickNewFile(fileUri: Uri) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        intent.type = "*/*"
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, fileUri)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true)
        startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
```

When fileUri is in `file://` format, DocumentsProvider will won't open in file's directory, showing default directory instead.
After user selects the new custom file, `onActivityResult` method will provide a new Uri, like `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fdata%2Fcom.example.testsapp%2Ffiles%2FcustomFile.txt`

When using this Uri with `pickNewFile` method, it will open on file's directory.

Is there a way to convert `file://` type Uri to a `content://` type Uri?

Answer (score -1):

No. Such conversion is not possible in Storage Access Framework as the content uri migh point to a storage file, files on flash drive or even a cloud provider

```
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider
```

Comment: That will not be the reason i think.

Comment: @Omkar I don't see how is this relevant, when I want to make conversion from a file:// to content:// Uri. In this case file is known to be present in storage